# Is it possible to graphics on a bitmap in easeljs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

i want to draw a circle on an image in easeljs.

My actual status:
In my canvas 1200 x 800 is a bitmap 9000 x 1000.
The image got a "pressmove" function, so i can navigate from the left to the right of the panorama and from the top to the bottom.

I want to draw a circle/shape onto the image/bitmap. 
For example at the coordinate of the image x:3000, y:500.
With my actual attempt to do this i created a container and added the bitmap and the shape in there. If i say bitmap.x/y = shape.x/y, the shape stays where it belongs to be but i need to tie it a specific coordinate.

[image: example picture]

The picture shows my actual view, the whole picture and the point (x,y) where i want to draw a circle onto the picture. So if i am showing this part of the picture there should be the point.

Do you guys have any idea how to do this?

**Problem Solved**
As @Lenny said, moving the container instead is moving both of the displayed objects. That's the result i wanted.

Comment: It sounds like your pressmove is moving the bitmap. Put the event on the container instead, so both objects move together.

Comment: @Lanny This works fine! Thanks.